# I want to concatenate a couple of variables with unknown types in a string

Tags: javascript

concatenation with pluses might lead to unexpected results,
In fact I want to get the result 123

```js
var one = 1;
var two = 2;
var three = '3';
var result = one + two + three;
alert(result);//I want-> 123
```

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640041/how-to-validation-of-input-text-field-in-ajax?noredirect=1#comment58961736_35640041

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var one = 1;
var two = 2;
var three = '3';

var result = ''.concat(one, two, three); //"123"
alert(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

> `+''` will cast it to string

Try this:

```js
var one = 1;
var two = 2;
var three = '3';
var result = one + '' + two + '' + three;
alert(result);
```